# What's the solution to this error?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
if($placed != true){    
  $_SESSION["eventid"][]   = "$r[id]";
  $_SESSION["selection"][] = "$selection";
  $_SESSION["title"][] = "$r[hometeam] - $r[awayteam]";
```

And the error is:

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home2/**/bet/add_bet.php on line 54
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home2/**/bet/add_bet.php on line 55
```

I know it has to do with an array; but which would be the solution here??? Im confused!

It's not like i can type `$_SESSION["eventid"][]   = array();`

[FULL CODE CAN BE SEEN HERE](http://pastebin.com/jdh5N6pC)

Comment: ...and the errors are descriptive enough to tell you the solution.

Comment: If more of your code would be relevant, you should post it in the question, not on a different site with a link. Besides, I looked at your code and the declaration of `$_SESSION['eventid']` isn't there anyhow.

Comment: I have tried to paste it in the post but it was not allowed.. what do you mean? Does session_start(); did not make the trick for you?

Answer (score 3):

If you `var_dump` your session variables, you will see that you have defined `$_SESSION['eventid']` et al. as strings somewhere in your code. As such, treating them as arrays will fail.

You will need to initialise your session variables to arrays explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer! The full code has been pasted in pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt use double quotes, also you need youse single quotes in `$r`, also use concatenation with single quotes:

```
     $_SESSION["eventid"][]   = $r['id'];
     $_SESSION["selection"][] = $selection;
     $_SESSION["title"][] = $r['hometeam'] .' - ' . $r['awayteam'];
```

I think you want something like this:

```
    $_SESSION["eventid"] = $r['id'];
    $_SESSION["selection"] = $selection;
    $_SESSION["title"] = $r['hometeam'] .' - ' . $r['awayteam'];
```

Comment: The last one should be a string, I guess.

Comment: You need string casts on all of those to be compatible. It _probably_ doesn't matter though.